How to reload page after product removal from Cart - Woocommerce
I have this code snippet:
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'empty_cart_redirection' );
function empty_cart_redirection(){
    if(is_cart() && WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
       wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink('8') );
       exit;
    }
}

This code redirect the user to the homepage if the cart is empty. The only problem is that the condition WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 is only true after page refresh. How can I change it so that the cart is updated when a product is removed ?
I tried the above code snippet expecting it to fix the problem, but it never enters the if statement. It only does so after manually refreshing the page.

To refresh the cart page after individual product removal, you can use Woocommerce Javascript Event.
Add the following code in the footer of the cart page:
<script>
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'removed_from_cart', function(){
  window.location.reload(); 
});
</script>

OR
If you need to refresh the cart page after empty the cart, use the following code:
<script>
    jQuery( document.body ).on( 'wc_cart_emptied', function(){
      window.location.reload(); 
    });
</script>


Thank you, I've tried it this solution but the event doesn't fire.

Did you try clear the cache?

Both scripts are working fine for me. You should try to troubleshoot your website. Hopefully, it will help.
